# API returning crazy results for 2 word searches

Tags: foursquare

Starting fairly recently, the API has started returning crazy results for 2 word searches.  For example:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?oauth_token=XXX&query=local_edition&radius=35000&ll=37.8%2C-122.4&limit=20&intent=browse
```

Will only return things matching 'ion' it seems.  If I search for either 'local' or 'edition', the intended location is one of the first few results.

Is it time to stop replacing spaces with underscores?  For a while, that was the only way to get reasonable results when searching for multiple words. (see this thread for more information: [What's the best way to tune my Foursquare API search queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945377/whats-the-best-way-to-tune-my-foursquare-api-search-queries))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting results for "ion", but if you replace the underscore with a plus sign or `%20`, it seems to work fine for me:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fquery%3Dlocal+edition%26radius%3D35000%26ll%3D37.8%252C-122.4%26limit%3D20%26intent%3Dbrowse

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fquery%3Dlocal%2520edition%26radius%3D35000%26ll%3D37.8%252C-122.4%26limit%3D20%26intent%3Dbrowse

Comment: Weirdly, queries for XXXXX_XXXXion result in a search for "ion" but *only* if it's five characters, underscore, four characters, then "ion". This does not happen with other numbers of characters but it does happen with other values of "ion" e.g., "bar". See for yourself at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fquery%3DXXXXX_XXXXion%26radius%3D35000%26ll%3D37.8%252C-122.4%26limit%3D20%26intent%3Dbrowse

Comment: Yeah, I just changed things back to not replace spaces with underscores.  I guess they finally fixed the issue with including 2 words in your query, and broke underscores in the process. :(